# UI elements dispatchers - which to use?

Tags: c#, wpf, dispatcher, ui-thread

I'm trying to fully understand the mechanism behind using the dispatcher in C# WPF application and came up with the question I cannot find an answer for. I hope the community can help me.

### The setting

Imagine we have a user control with a **button** and a **label**. After pressing the button some **time-consuming operation** starts and once it finishes, it places the results (say, the execution duration) in the label.

For the sake of positive user experience the following conditions should be met:

- while the **time-consuming operation** is running, the UI must remain responsive
- in order to prevent the user from running the **time-consuming operation** in parallel several times, once it starts the **button** should be disabled. It gets enabled once the **time-consuming operation** finishes.

### The implementation

The simplest `xaml`:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WhichDispatcher">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Button x:Name="button" Content="Execute time-consuming operation" Click="button_Click" />
        <Label x:Name="label" Content="Not yet executed" />
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

And the code behind:

```
public partial class WhichDispatcher : UserControl
{
    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.button.IsEnabled = false;
        Task.Run(() => 
        {
            this.TimeConsumingOperation();
        });
    }

    private void TimeConsumingOperation()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

The method where **time-consuming operation** is invoked will run on a separate thread to prevent UI lock up.

### The Time-Consuming Operation

I now focus on the implementation of the method that will perform the **time-consuming operation**. Once it's finished the UI elements need to be updated, in a dispatcher as they can't be called from another thread.

```
    private void TimeConsumingOperation()
    {
        TimeSpan runningTime = new TimeSpan();
        // Run the time-consuming operation
        // Let's assume that the runningTime variable will be set as a result of the above operation.

        this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => 
        {
            this.button.IsEnabled = true;
            this.label.Content = string.Format("The time-consuming operation took {0} seconds", runningTime.TotalSeconds);
        });
    }
```

The UI update will be performed in the `UserControl`'s dispatcher. Now for the question.

### The question

The UI update can be also performed in the elements' dispatchers separately, like this:

```
    private void TimeConsumingOperation()
    {
        TimeSpan runningTime = new TimeSpan();
        // Run the time-consuming operation
        // Let's assume that the runningTime variable will be set as a result of the above operation.

        this.button.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => 
        {
            this.button.IsEnabled = true;
        });

        this.label.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
        {
            this.label.Content = string.Format("The time-consuming operation took {0} seconds", runningTime.TotalSeconds);
        });

    }
```

And the question is: is there any difference in which dispatcher I'm using? Should I always try to use the smallest-scope dispatcher or it doesn't matter and I can always go for the largest scope dispatcher available (`UserControl`s in this case) as it is the UI-thread dispatcher anyway?

Comment: You should `await Task.Run(...)`, as shown in the answer below. The important point is that you do not use any Dispatcher at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "different" `Dispatcher`s you see are actually the same single `Dispatcher` of the UI thread in WPF.

But your case is a classical pattern for an `async` method.

First, prepare all you need on the UI thread (disable button).
Then await the long-running task.
Finally, post-process the task (enable button, set output).

You don't need to bother with `Dispatcher` using this approach.

```
private async void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.button.IsEnabled = false;
    TimeSpan runningTime = new TimeSpan();

    await Task.Run(() => 
    {
        this.TimeConsumingOperation();
    });

    this.label.Content = string.Format("The time-consuming operation took {0} seconds", runningTime.TotalSeconds);
    this.button.IsEnabled = true;
}
```

However, if you want to interact with the UI *from inside of the long-running task being executed on a background thread*, you will need to consider the following:

- Use the MVVM pattern and data bindings. WPF will marshal the data across the threads automatically.
- Manually marshal the data using `Dispatcher`. Not recommended, but sometimes unavoidable.

Comment: Thank you. It's more than I was asking. Silly of me but I was not aware that UI action event handlers can be marked `async`. One learns something new every day.

Comment: @Mike Please also note that event handlers are the only methods that may be declared `async void`. Any other async method without return value should always be declared as `async Task Method(...)` and be awaited.